# Creating a trigger that will update a column with an interval

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, triggers, sql-insert

Sorry if this is a noob question as I am one right now but
I am seem to be having a problem on the `mysql trigger`. I am trying to create a trigger that will automatically updates the data **dateValid** with an interval of 5 minutes from the **dateCreated's** data after insert.

```
DROP TRIGGERIF EXISTS `restrictionotp`;TRIGGER `add_interval` beforeINSERT 
on `date` FOR each row 
UPDATE date 
SET    datevalid=date_add(new.datecreated, interval 5 minute) 
WHERE  dateid=new.dateid
```

The code above was successfully been created but once I try to insert a data on the said table this error shows up

```
Can't update table 'verification' in stored function/trigger because
 it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger
```

Thanks for answering my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `set` the `new` value in the trigger. The database will then insert the modified value instead of the original.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER Add_Interval 
    BEFORE INSERT ON verification 
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET new.datevalid = new.datecreated + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you, it has finally worked. it looks like i need to thoroughly study the SQL again.